# TypeError: ARIMA() got an unexpected keyword argument 'order'

Tags: python, time-series, typeerror, forecasting, arima

I am trying to run ARIMA model like,

'''

```
    model = ARIMA(data, order=(5, 1, 1))
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=False)
    # make prediction
    yhat = model_fit.predict(len(data), len(data), typ='levels')
```

'''

but getting the below error

**TypeError: ARIMA() got an unexpected keyword argument 'order'**

Can someone please tell me what the error is.

Thank you